# angularjs understanding ng-repeat behavior in Modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I am confused and need assistance understanding how ng-repeat works in a modal. I have combed through multiple other threads and posts seemingly related to my question but none of them have helped me understand whats happening underneath.

I have a page with a modal on it, the modal doesn't open unless a user clicks a button on the main page.  In the modal is an ng-repeat; when the ng-repeat is done I need to call a function that attaches a `<canvas>` to a DIV in each of the elements created by the ng-repeat.  In the ng-repeat, the function call to generate the canvas's needs to be triggered AFTER the HTML is rendered using a `ng-init="$last && genQRCode()"`

MODAL

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in club.tickets" ng-init="$last && genQRCode()">
   <div id="ticketID_{{ticket.ticketID}}">
      ... genQRCode() will create the <canvas> and attach it here ...
   </div>
</div>
```

When the main page loads though, I am seeing the `genQRCode()` function being called - even if the modal is never opened.  As a result, the `<canvas>`s are generated but can't attach to the DIVs because the Modal ng-repeat hasn't generated them yet.  And when the modal is opened, the DIVs are created - but the `genQRCode()` is never called and thus no canvas's are attached to the newly created DIVs.

I am using ng-repeat with `ng-init="$last && someFunction()"` in other areas of my code and they all execute and display just fine.  But inside of a modal everything is not working as expected.

1. What is happening here?
2. Why is `genQRCode()` being called during the primary page load (and the modal hasn't opened yet)?
3. Why isn't `genQRCode()` being called at the end of the ng-repeat after the Modal is opened?
4. What is the best way to manage this - as I need the `genQRCode()` function called AFTER the ng-repeat has rendered the DIVs to the DOM?

Thaks.